# Arrays Equals Ignoring Order

Tags: java, arrays, equals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Checking equality of arrays (order doesnt matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154305/java-checking-equality-of-arrays-order-doesnt-matter)

I have two arrays :

```
String[] a1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] a2 = {"c", "b", "a"};
```

I need to check if both contains same elements (and of same length) **irrespective of order** of elements.

I tried `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)` but it considers order of element.
`org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils` does not provide this thing.

I know I can achieve the same by creating my own method (checking for same length, then sorting both array and then using `Arrays.equals(a1, a2)`) but wanted to know if this thing is provided in any API or there is more smart way to do the same.

Comment: Have you tried Arrays.sort(a2), and then check to see if they are equal?

Comment: You could sort the arrays before you call Arrays.equals but this would be costly.

Comment: A probably more efficient solution would be to add the items of first array to a hashset and then check what items of the second arrays are yet in the hashset.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you have these arrays in something inheriting from Collection, you can just use `collection.containsAll( otherCollection )` from the Collection interface.  However, you'll also need to compare the lengths of the two to verify that one set isn't a superset of the other.

(Thanks go to Aardvarkk and piegames.)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)

Note: This will work up to a point.  This is defined to check for *at least one* of any element existing.  That is, if you have 3 `a` values in one collection, and 7 `a` values in the other, that will *not* necessarily cause it to call them unequal.

Examples:

```
[a, b, c] == [c, a, b]             // Works -- Mixed order
[a, b, c, d, d] == [a, b, d, c, d] // Works -- Mixed order with repeats
[a, b, c, d, d] == [a, b, b, c, d] // FAILS -- Different repeats
[a, b, c, d, d] != [a, b, c, d]    // Works -- Length differs with repeats
[a, b, c, d] != [a, b, c]          // Works -- Length differs
[a, b, d] != [a, b, c]             // Works -- Disjoint sets
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to check containsAll in both directions? A one-way evaluation would return true for a set which was a superset of the other, which doesn't appear to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @aardvarkk Excellent point!  I'll edit my post.

Comment: This doesn't handle duplicates correctly. The JavaDoc doesn't make this clear, but `a.containsAll(b)` iff `a` contains **at least one** `x` for each element `x` in `b`. As an example, try testing with `a={5}`, `b={5,5}`. They're not equal when viewed as multisets, but `containsAll` returns `true` in both directions.

Comment: At least this is the interpretation of `containsAll` that's used in practice. Even Guava's [Multiset.containsAll](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html#containsAll) "does not take into account the occurrence count of an element".

Comment: @Daniel Right, this was covered by the portion of my answer labeled "Note".

Comment: @aardvarkk Wouldn't it be enough to just check the length of both Arrays instead of the second containsAll? (Assuming there are no duplicates)

Comment: @piegames That's absolutely correct.  I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of that.  I will update this answer.

Answer (score 29):

i think it may work for you, sort first array with

```
Arrays.sort(Object[]);
```

and after that you can compare with

```
Arrays.equals(Object[],Object[]);
```

complete code is:

```
String[] a1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
String[] a2 = {"c", "b", "a"};
Arrays.sort(a2);

boolean result= Arrays.equals(a1, a2);
```

Comment: Sorting should happen on both a1 and a2. There is no guarantee a1 is already sorted.

Comment: Even then, sorting isn't always a good idea: it mutates the data. If you don't want it you have to duplicate the data which costs time and memory.

Comment: This won't work if the objects don't implement comparable

Comment: @piegames but the definition of `List::equals` includes order (read Javadoc: `... two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.`). So if one desires to check for equality with all the same `List::equals` parameters (i.e., exact same elements) but ignore order, sorting is inevitable.

Answer (score 15):

Convert the lists to sets before comparing them :

```
new HashSet( Arrays.asList( a1 )).equals( new HashSet( Arrays.asList( a2 ) ));
```

Alternatively, you can sort the arrays using `Arrays.sort()` but that might break code which depends on the order of the elements in the arrays.

Comment: That only works if there are no duplicates.

Comment: This is also more efficient as it runs O(m+n) whereas doing containsAll on a list is O(n^2+m^2)

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.util.Set` method `equals`. Compares two sets  have the same size, and every member of the specified set is contained in other set.