# Check If a particular list is present in "List of Lists" irrespective of order

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have a **list of lists** like

```
[[0, 5, 10, -1], [1, 8, 3, 4], [2, 9, 6, 7]]
```

Now I want to search If the above list of lists contain
**[8,1,4,3]**
I simply want to ignore the order of elements.
How can I achieve this.
** I tried contains but it fails when the order is different.

**Edit:**
The code I'm using

```
for(List<Integer> innerSList : PermutaionS_toDraw)
        {int elem_trans = 0;

        if(!Final.contains(innerSList))
        {
        Final.add(PermutaionS_toDraw.get(PermutaionS_toDraw.indexOf(innerSList)));
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far ?

Comment: @JFPicard, I used .contains method. but that fails when the order changes.

Comment: Can't you use set? Or you have repeated elements too in the list of lists?

Comment: @rafaelim I gave a small list of 3 lists as an example. my list size can be upto 100 or more, and these are generated at run time.

Comment: @sheldoncooper please see my answer below. It should explain exactly what you need

Comment: Ok, did you already checked this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009357/arrays-equals-ignoring-order

Comment: @BrandonLaidig please check the code i added in my post.

Comment: @sheldoncooper I assume Final is the search list?

Comment: @rafaelim yes. It worked only if the order is same as of the sublist.

Comment: @BrandonLaidig Final is also a list of lists

Comment: @sheldoncooper see my updated answer

Comment: Can the inner lists contain duplicate elements? A `containsAll` check would consider [4, 4, 0, 1] and [4, 0, 1, 1] to be a match.

Comment: No, inner list doesn't contain duplicate

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over all the lists, for each list check they are the same length as the one you are looking to compare and if so call [containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) to check it contains all the values.

```
for(List<Integer> innerList : permutaionsToDraw){
    int elemTrans = 0;

    if(final.size() != innerList.size() || !final.containsAll(innerSList)) {
        final.add(permutaionsToDraw.get(permutaionsToDraw.indexOf(innerList)));
   }
}
```

**Note**

I renamed your variables to keep with Java naming conventions

Comment: What's the point of comparing the size of Final with innerSList, The former is a list of lists

Comment: from my understanding final is the one he is looking for so it has to be the same size as the innerlist. He has to compare the lengths because one could be a superset of the other.

Comment: @sheldoncooper basically all you have to do is the one you are comparing make sure its the same size and then call contains all which will tell you if all the values are contained, you wont run into issue with order.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, you'll want to do a contains, however I think you're doing it at the wrong level. Instead of seeing if the main list contains your sublist, you'd want to iterate through the main list and check if each of it's values contains all of your search value. For example,

```
for (List<String> subList : mainList) {
   if (subList.containsAll(searchList) {
      return true;
   }
}
return false;
```

This will loop through your main list and check if each of it's children contains all the values of what you're searching for. Hope this helps and that I've explained it clearly!

Note: This depends on the type of collections you are using. A standard String[] won't work with this code

Edit: To react to your posting of the code. I believe all you'd need to change is the contains to a contains all. Contains will only look for an exact match within Final, however contains all will compare the contents and check if that collection of integers is contained at all within Final. So, it should look something like this

```
List<List<Integer>> finalCopy = new LinkedList<>();
for(List<Integer> innerSList : PermutaionS_toDraw){
   for (List<Integer> subList : Final) {
      if(!subList.containsAll(innerSList)) {
         finalCopy.add(innerSList);
      }
   }
}
Final.addAll(finalCopy);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if a sub list contains `searchList` and more elements

Comment: Yes it would. This would return true if the sub list contains at least all of them that are within searchList. It doesn't matter if the sublist contains more and OP didn't specify that it had to be an exact match

Comment: That doesn't mean it works for the conditions I describe. How do you know that it doesn't matter if the sublist contains more?

Comment: Because OP clarified that the collections are the same size in an above comment

Comment: @lucasvw are you willing to remove your downvote now?

Comment: @sheldoncooper my mistake. You'll also need to iterate through the Final list like my first example states. See the updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using .ContainsAll() method on any Implementing classes of List Interface (ArrayList in my example). The parameter of ContainsAll() takes a Collection and ContainsAll() returns a boolean value.
Please see : [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

If you are already working with arrays you can convert them using Arrays.asList()

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integersList = new ArrayList<>();
    integersList.add(1);
    integersList.add(2);
    integersList.add(3);
    integersList.add(4);

    List<Integer> integersList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    integersList2.add(5);
    integersList2.add(6);
    integersList2.add(7);
    integersList2.add(8);

    List<Integer> integersList3 = new ArrayList<>();
    integersList3.add(1);
    integersList3.add(2);
    integersList3.add(3);
    integersList3.add(4);

    List<List> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfLists.add(integersList);
    listOfLists.add(integersList2);
    listOfLists.add(integersList3);

    List<Integer> numbersToLookFor = new ArrayList<>();
    numbersToLookFor.add(1);
    numbersToLookFor.add(2);
    numbersToLookFor.add(3);
    numbersToLookFor.add(4);

    for (List l : listOfLists) {
        if (l.containsAll(numbersToLookFor)) {
            System.out.println(l + "does contain " + numbersToLookFor);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] does contain [1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8] does NOT contain [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4] does contain [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Edit: if you were to change the numbers to look for to a different order it will still return true.

```
 //CHANGED from 1 2 3 4 --> 3 1 4 2
    List<Integer> numbersToLookFor = new ArrayList<>();
    numbersToLookFor.add(3);
    numbersToLookFor.add(1);
    numbersToLookFor.add(4);
    numbersToLookFor.add(2);

    for (List l : listOfLists) {
        if (l.containsAll(numbersToLookFor)) {
            System.out.println(l + " does contain " + numbersToLookFor);
        } else
            System.out.println(l + " does NOT contain " + numbersToLookFor);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] does contain [3, 1, 4, 2]
[5, 6, 7, 8] does NOT contain [3, 1, 4, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4] does contain [3, 1, 4, 2]
```

Comment: What If I check [1,2,3,4] contains [3,1,2,4] or not.

Comment: @sheldoncooper containsAll covers that

Comment: @sheldoncooper see my second example

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. for every sublist this snippet checks if the searchlist is the same size, contains the same elements (in any order) and is not already in the Final list of lists.

```
for(List<Integer> innerSList : PermutaionS_toDraw)
        {    
        if(searchlist.size() == innerSList.size() && searchList.containsAll(innerSList)
           && !Final.contains(searchList))
        {
        Final.add(PermutaionS_toDraw.get(PermutaionS_toDraw.indexOf(innerSList)));
        }
}
```

Comment: The search list is actually each sublist within `Final`. OP essentially needs to iterate through each sublist in `Final` and see if it contains the given list from `PermutationS_toDraw` using the containsAll. The size check here is also irrelevant

Comment: @Brandon Laidig Thats not how i understand OP. In my answer Final is the list of sublists that fit the criteria. Searchlist([8,1,4,3] in OP's Question) is a sublist that needs to be compared with the lists in PermutationS_toDraw ([[0, 5, 10, -1], [1, 8, 3, 4], [2, 9, 6, 7]] in OP's question). OP?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if the sublist contains elements regardless of order that is the same thing as checking if they have the same number of each element, or their sorted lists are equal. So what you want to do is either count each number in your list and add it to a HashMap, or compare the two lists in sorted order

Comment: all of the sublists have same size. I have retrieve the sublist and use it in some other steps.